# How may I give the current time as the modification time for a file or directory in a tar archive

Tags: linux, shell-script, tar, timestamps

I want to create a `tar` archive which will have files and directories. I need to change the modification time of these files and directories so that their modification timestamp is the current date and time when I'm doing the compression. How may I do that in shell script?

Comment: `touch` all files before archiving them?

Comment: How can i do that.
Can you just tell the command to do that?
What i can do on directories

Comment: It's `touch`. See `man touch` for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `tar`, you can use the `--mtime` option to store arbitrary modification times; in your case,

```
tar cf archive.tar --mtime="@$(date +%s)" ...
```

will use the current time for all modification times stored in the archive.

Comment: appreciate the answer

Comment: This is a good hint for `libfind` that is used by `star` and many other programs: it seems to be a good idea to add  `-chatime`, `-chctime`, `-chmtime` primaries to modify these values in `struct stat`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the modification timestamp on everything under a directory `dir` (including the directory itself):

```
find dir -exec touch {} +
```

You would do this just before you create your `tar` archive of the `dir` directory.

Comment: Do you really like to shredder all time stamps in the file system?

Comment: @schily Only in the directory that will be archived.